# Weird way to increase the size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, strncpy

I thought normally you can't increase the size of an array.
But what if I do:

> char arr[4];
>
> strncpy(arr,"12347777",8);

It shows the legnth is increased when I call strlen(arr).
Can someone explain to me what happened there?

Comment: This kind of undefined behavior, writing past end of allocated buffer, is commonly called *buffer overrun*, and is on of the most common causes of security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't made the array larger. You've stomped on random pieces of memory after the end of the array.

`strlen` does not return the length of an array, even in normal conditions. It says how long a string is. Since you just put eight characters (plus a null terminator) there, it's returning 8. However, this is undefined behavior! Because you've corrupted memory, you could crash, or it could return a random number (according to the standard, anything is possible). In a less simplistic piece of code, in fact, this would likely lead to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

You just made a huge bug. It can lead in memory corruption and misbehave of your program. It doesn't change real array size but overwrite memory where array lies and which follows. So you wrote four chars `{'1', '2', '3', '4'}` in array but then `{'7', '7', '7', '7'}` to the following memory. You are lucky enough there was zeroed next byte so `strlen(arr)` shows you size 8. It is simple buggy and you should not do it. Note `"12347777"` is pointer into memory containing `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '7', '7', '7', '7', '\0'}` and you had copied only 8 chars so missed terminating zero byte.